# extract values from nested dictionary in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas column, one sample value looks like this

```
 colName1 {'key1': {'key2': {'ke3': {'label': '3 minutes, 16 seconds'}}, 'simpleText': '3:16'}, 'style': 'DEFAULT'}
```

tried this but din't work.

```
df1['XYZ'] = df1['colName1'].apply(lambda x: x['key1']['key2']['simpleText'])
```

How can I retrieve the value of 'simpleText' which equals to 3:16

Comment: please provide an unambiguous reproducible input.

Comment: this nested json is the input for 1 dataframe with 1 row`{'key1': {'key2': {'ke3': {'label': '3 minutes, 16 seconds'}}, 'simpleText': '3:16'}, 'style': 'DEFAULT'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try

```py
df1['XYZ'] = df1['colName1'].str['key1'].str['simpleText']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
x['key1']['simpleText']
```

`key2` is redundant.

Comment: its giving me error `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Then probably some value of your `colName1` is not in the format that you've provided here

Comment: the`colName1 ` is showing object as datatype.

Comment: `df['colName1']` contains many values (yes, objects)

Answer (score 0):

#Try this:

```
val['XYZ'] = val['key1']['simpleText']
print(val['XYZ'])
```

#output: 3:16

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).